# Jest Asynchronous API Mocking

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I have searched this issue on stack-overflow, but couldn't find anything similar to me use case.

I have container component like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// API
import BookingAPI from '../../../../api/BookingAPI';

class CustomerProfilePage extends Component {
  state = {
    list: [],
    totalRecords: 0,
    pageNo: 1,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { pageNo } = this.state;
    this.onGetBookingList({ pageNo });
  }

  onGetBookingList = async ({ pageNo = 0 }) => {
    const { match } = this.props;
    try {
      const result = await BookingAPI.onGetBookingList({
        passengerId: match.params.customerId,
        sortProperties: ['id'],
        limitCount: 10,
        pageNo,
      });
      this.setState({
        list: result.items,
        totalRecords: result.totalRecords,
     });
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log('error is', error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default CustomerProfilePage;
```

I want to test `BookingAPI.onGetBookingList` in my `this.onGetBookingList` method.

So far this is what I have tried, am I missing something here..

This is my `CustomerProfilePage.test.js` file below

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

// Components
import CustomerProfilePage from './CustomerProfilePage';

function setup() {
  const props = {
     match: {
       params: {
         customerId: 1,
       },
     },
  };
  return shallow(<CustomerProfilePage {...props} />);
}

describe('CustomerProfilePage', () => {
  it('Should update state on onGetBookingList call', async () => {
    jest.mock('../../../../api/BookingAPI', () => ({
      onGetBookingList: () => {
        const data = { items: [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }], totalRecords: 1 };
        return jest.fn().mockReturnValue(data);
      },
    }));
    const wrapper = setup();
    await wrapper.instance().onGetBookingList({ pageNo: 1 });
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.state().totalRecords).toBe(1); // should be 1, but is 0
 });
});
```

For the purpose of simplicity I have not written the code in my `render` because I wanted to focus on the code part where I am mocking an API call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `onGetBookingList` has to be an async function

you can define async method like this:

```
jest.mock('../../../../api/BookingAPI', () => ({
    async onGetBookingList() {
        return data;
    }
}));
```

or you can use jest.fn() which retuns a Promise

```
jest.mock('../../../../api/BookingAPI', () => ({
    onGetBookingList: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(data))
}));
```

or use jest.fn().mockResolvedValue()

```
jest.mock('../../../../api/BookingAPI', () => ({
    onGetBookingList: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(data)
}));
```

and then

```
import { onGetBookingList } from '../../../../api/BookingAPI';

it('should be working with all of the above mocks', async () => {
    const { totalRecords } = await onGetBookingList();
    expect(totalRecords).toBe(1);
}
```

[working exmaple](https://repl.it/repls/GraciousWellwornPriority)

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way where I can invoke `this.onGetBookingList` in my test and test `BookingAPI.onGetBookingList` method from that function, instead of testing it directly. Also if i test it directly will my code coverage be covered like this?

Comment: The test above proves that the mock is working. You don't need to test it directly. It  is supposed to be called by your implementation which you're testing, because it relays on the `BookingAPI`

Comment: I know, this is what has been bothering me. Your tests work, but my coverage is still not 100% because jest is not covering the lines inside `this.onGetBookingList`
I can test each API like this, but my code is still not giving me coverage inside those methods.

Comment: Jest's coverage reporting is working just fine and probably you should ask a new question, it's offtopic here

Comment: Thank you for your support.