# Jest async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to jest/enzyme and I try to test a function. The test is attempting to test that `getData()` sets the array returned in the state.

This is how it looks :

```
getData () {
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/targeting-data').then(response => {
    this.setState({
      targetingData: response.data,
      load: true
    })
  })
}

componentDidMount () {
  this.interval = setTimeout(() => {
    this.getData()
  }, 3000)
}
```

My first test :

```
import FormWrapper from './../containers/FormWrapper/FormWrapper'

const mockGetData = jest.spyOn(FormWrapper.prototype, 'getData')

it('testing', () => {
  mockGetData()
  expect(formWrapper.state().targetingData).toHaveLength(8)
})
```

And I got fails :

```
expect(received).toHaveLength(length)

Expected value to have length:
  8
Received:
  []
received.length:
  0
```

My second test :

```
it('getDataFunc', (done) => {
  mockGetData().then(res => {
    expect(res).toHaveLength(8)
    done()
  })
})
```

And I got fails :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

(node:6302) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
(node:6302) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
```

I am confused about how to test it, I will be glad about any suggestions. Thank you

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async this may help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are  variety of options for mocking remote API calls, so you don't have to modify your code to test it

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @varit05 . but I am still confused about how to implement it

Comment: hi @Mikkel can you show me one of them?

Comment: it's probably the same ( or at least very close): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876091/jest-asynchronous-api-mocking

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [async/await](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#async-await) approach to test your function `getData` as it is `async`, but first you need to mock axios `get` method because you don't want include the external API call in your test, instead just mock its response:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {shallow, mount} from "enzyme";
import FormWrapper from './../containers/FormWrapper/FormWrapper'

jest.mock('axios'); // for mocking axios

it('test', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<FormWrapper />); // I'm using shallow render, you could use mount if you want to
    const instance = wrapper.instance(); // get an instance in order to call getData() directly
    // mock axios get with a response
    axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([
        {
            id: 1,
            val: 'val1'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            val: 'val2'
        }
    ]));
    await instance.getData();
    expect(wrapper.state().targetingData).toHaveLength(2); // this is the length of the mocked response I have added here
});
```

There is something I want to point out here about this function. In my opinion, the function `getData()` you are trying to test is actually not a good subject to testing as it doesn't contain any logic you have written.

It gets some data from API (which is not something you own), then it uses `this.setState` to set the state (and you don't want to test React's behavior executing `setState` to update your state).

In case you want to have your `state` populated with some data in order to use for testing other functions in the component, then I suggest you set it manually like so:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<FormWrapper />);
wrapper.setState({
    targetingData: {...}
});
```

So that you concentrate more on functions and parts of code containing more logic you have written yourself.

Comment: actually, there is some logic in the function, I actually need setState to be tested

Comment: Ok, you go with the way I explained in the answer.